# Error code 13 on Biometric dialog closure

Tags: android

I am implementing Android's Biometric prompt in my app and when I close the prompt by pressing cancel button, I get `onAuthenticationError` callback with `errorCode` as 13. But, I don't see any error code with value 13 in the documentation (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/biometrics/BiometricPrompt.html). Could someone help?

Answer (score 1):

Ah, after browsing through Android Biometric source code, found this, `BiometricConstants.ERROR_NEGATIVE_BUTTON`. It should be captured in the class documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking at the android.hardware.biometric documentation instead of the androidx.biometric [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/biometric/BiometricPrompt.html#ERROR_NEGATIVE_BUTTON). The `ERROR_NEGATIVE_BUTTON` API on androidx.biometric is a slight divergence from the `OnClickListener` in the framework's version.